# wget downloading only PDFs from website

Tags: pdf, wget

I am trying to download all PDFs from http://www.fayette-pva.com/.

I believe the problem is that when hovering over the link to download the PDF chrome shows the URL in the bottom left hand corner without a `.pdf` file extension. I saw and used another forum answer similar to this but the `.pdf` extension was used for the URL when hovering over the PDF link with my cursor. I have tried the same code that is in the link below but it doesn't pick up the PDF files.

Here is the code I have been testing with:

```
wget --no-directories -e robots=off -A.pdf -r -l1 \
    http://www.fayette-pva.com/sales-reports/salesreport03-feb-09feb2015/
```

I am using this on a single page of which I know that it has a PDF on it.

The complete code should be something like

```
wget --no-directories -e robots=off -A.pdf -r http://www.fayette-pva.com/
```

Related answer: [WGET problem downloading pdfs from website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416880/wget-problem-downloading-pdfs-from-website)

I am not sure if downloading the entire website would work and if it wouldn't take forever. How do I get around this and download only the PDFs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the problem is precisely what you stated: The URLs do not contain regular or absolute filenames, but are calls to a script/servlet/... which hands out the actual files.

The solution is to use the `--content-disposition` option, which tells `wget` to honor the `Content-Disposition` field in the HTTP response, which carries the actual filename:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
(...)
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="SalesIndexThru09Feb2015.pdf"
(...)
Connection: close
```

This option is supported in `wget` at least since version `1.11.4`, which is already 7 years old.

So you would do the following:

```
wget --no-directories --content-disposition -e robots=off -A.pdf -r \
    http://www.fayette-pva.com/
```

Comment: very underrated ans - thank you!!